# Род названий министерств

Tags: род, сокращения, названия

Напишите, пожалуйста, какой род у Минкавказа и Минобрнауки. Я полагаю, что средний. Я права?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, верно: род в таких аббревиатурах определяется главным словом "министерство", которое, очевидно, среднего рода.

Тем не менее употребление слова "Минкавказ" в мужском роде также верно (это связано с тем, что грамматические признаки этого слова указывают на его сходство с существительными мужского рода; ср.: *нет* Минкавказ**а** и заказ**а**, *любуюсь* Минкавказ**ом** и заказ**ом** и т. д.

Comment: Я бы не рискнул произнести "Минкавказ постановило", с Минобрнауки - нет проблем. Помните "ТАСС уполномочен..."? Агентство тоже среднего рода, но тип окончания может влиять сильнее, чем род видового наименования.

Comment: @Alex_ander а вы уверены, что Минкавказ, а не Минкавказ**а**?

Comment: Минкавказ России: http://www.minkavkaz.gov.ru/

Comment: @Alex_ander благодарю, дополнил.